# System of linear differential equations - generalized eigenspaces

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to prove that if $f$ is a solution of the system $x'=Ax$ (where $A \in M_{n}(\Bbb R)$) such that $f(0)=x_0 \in G_\lambda$ ($G_\lambda $ is the generalized eigenspace for $\lambda$) then $f(t) \in G_\lambda \  \forall t \in \Bbb R$. 
I tried using the fact that $G_\lambda$ is invariant but I'm stuck...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is $f(t) = \exp(t A)\cdot  f(0) = \exp(t A)\cdot  x_0$.

Note that $G_{\lambda}$ equals the kernel of the operator $(A - \lambda \cdot I)^n$. $\ $  So it would be enough to prove the following:

If $(A - \lambda \cdot I)^n \cdot x_0 = 0$ then $(A - \lambda \cdot I)^n \cdot \exp(t A)\cdot  x_0=0$. But the operators $(A - \lambda \cdot I)^n$ and  $\exp(t A)$ commute (being both functions of the same operator $A$) and so $(A - \lambda \cdot I)^n \cdot \exp(t A) = \exp(t A) (A - \lambda \cdot I)^n$. You are pretty much done now.

Morally, the right approach $\it{is}$ to show that any subspace $G$ invariant under $A$ is invariant under $\exp(tA)$. One way would be to use 
$$\exp(tA) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{l=0}^n t^l/l! \cdot A^l   $$
see that $G$ is invariant under all $\sum_{l=0}^n t^l/l! \cdot A^l$ and use the fact that $G$ is closed. Another way is to show that $\exp(tA)$ is a polynomial in $A$ of degree $\le n-1$, that is, $\exp(tA)$ lies in the subalgebra $\mathbb{R}[A]$.